# XeLaTex and Fontspec crash trying to find woff file for some fonts but not others

Tags: xetex, footnotes, fontspec, ebgaramond

Running XeLaTex on this example results in a pdf as expected:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Cabin}
\begin{document}
\footnote{text}
\end{document}
```

Running XeLaTex on this example does not result in a pdf:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\begin{document}
\footnote{text}
\end{document}
```

An example without a footnote, but with body text, using EB Garamond works fine.

The trouble appears to be that the program is not finding the font for the footnote mark, i.e. the 8pt font:

```
xdvipdfmx:fatal: Cannot proceed without the font: /usr/share/font/woff/ebgaramond/EBGaramond08-Regular.woff

Output file removed.
```

It appears that the program is looking in the wrong place. The path should be

```
/usr/share/fonts/woff/ebgaramond/EBGaramond08-Regular.woff
```

Note the extra s on fonts.

So how come the program is looking in right place for everything else, including all the other Garamond fonts, but not this one?

I am using Kile on a Kubuntu 17.04 system.

Comment: Can XeTeX use WOFF fonts to begin with? I don't think so.

Comment: xelatex shouldn't use the woff font, if it is in the search path you should better use file names to avoid that they are used. See also https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/139/

Comment: I see. Well it is certainly trying to do so, and it seems to be the same problem as reported in that bug report, for which thanks. So the solution is probably as you say to specify file paths, which is a bit of a pain, but OK.

Answer (score 7):

For people that still meet this, to ensure that fontconfig does not return WOFF files, 
https://bugs.freedesktop.org/attachment.cgi?id=131636 (copied below) should be saved in the relevant place as  e.g.  `/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-woff.conf`

```
<fontconfig>
<!-- Reject WOFF fonts We don't register WOFF(2) fonts with fontconfig because of the W3C spec -->
 <selectfont>
  <rejectfont>
   <glob>/usr/share/fonts/woff/*</glob>
  </rejectfont>
 </selectfont>
</fontconfig>
```

Comment: changed to `<glob>*.woff</glob>` to cover fonts in my `~/.fonts` , `/usr/local/share/fonts` etc.