# XeLaTeX does not show diacritics characters correctly with EB Garamond font in docker container

Tags: xetex, fontspec, docker

On my MacOS with `brew` `mactex-no-gu` installed all works fine. Diacritics in generated PDF by XeTeX is displayed correctly.

Now I am trying to prepare docker image with XeTeX but there is a problem with displaying diacritics. I am using EB Garamond font.

### tex file

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}


    \chapter{Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy}

    \begin{flushleft}

    Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy

\textbf{Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy}

\textit{Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy}

 العَرَبِيَّة

 

 aaaטון ביץaaa

 ☺️♥️✌️‍♂️‍♂️

 Αν προ δετραcτο vερτερεμ, σιμιλιqθε μοδερατιθσ θτ vελ. Νθμqθαμ μινιμθμ cομπρεηενσαμ μει ει, σιτ προβο νοστρθδ οπορτερε εθ. Αγαμ ρεπριμιqθε τε ηισ, ιδ σιτ μαγνα προμπτα ινvενιρε, qθο ιν θνθμ οφφενδιτ οπορτεατ. Ιπσθμ vελιτ πρινcιπεσ αδ σεα, εξ προ διcτασ λαβιτθρ. Εθμ ετ vιρισ δελιcατισσιμι.


    \end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

### pdf file

[image]

### log file

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (TeX Live 2020/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex 2021.10.6)  7 OCT 2021 08:13
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**c6115e0d-b62d-4c15-841a-e1ca4c95cf7f.tex
(./c6115e0d-b62d-4c15-841a-e1ca4c95cf7f.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-01-09> xparse <2020-03-03>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls
Document Class: memoir 2020/10/04 v3.7n configurable book, report, article docu
ment class
\onelineskip=\skip47
\lxvchars=\skip48
\xlvchars=\skip49
\@memcnta=\count173
\c@@memmarkcntra=\count174
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
)
\stockheight=\skip50
\stockwidth=\skip51
\trimtop=\skip52
\trimedge=\skip53

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/mem10.clo
File: mem10.clo 2008/01/30 v0.3 memoir class 10pt size option
)
\binding=\skip54
\spinemargin=\skip55
\foremargin=\skip56
\uppermargin=\skip57
\lowermargin=\skip58
\headdrop=\skip59
\normalrulethickness=\skip60
\mem@maxheadheight=\skip61
\mem@maxfootheight=\skip62
\headwidth=\skip63
\c@storedpagenumber=\count175
\memPD=\dimen138
\m@mabparskip=\skip64
\thanksmarkwidth=\skip65
\thanksmarksep=\skip66
\droptitle=\skip67
\c@book=\count176
\c@part=\count177
\c@chapter=\count178
\c@section=\count179
\c@subsection=\count180
\c@subsubsection=\count181
\c@paragraph=\count182
\c@subparagraph=\count183
\beforechapskip=\skip68
\midchapskip=\skip69
\afterchapskip=\skip70
\chapindent=\skip71
\bottomsectionskip=\skip72
\secindent=\skip73
\beforesecskip=\skip74
\aftersecskip=\skip75
\subsecindent=\skip76
\beforesubsecskip=\skip77
\aftersubsecskip=\skip78
\subsubsecindent=\skip79
\beforesubsubsecskip=\skip80
\aftersubsubsecskip=\skip81
\paraindent=\skip82
\beforeparaskip=\skip83
\afterparaskip=\skip84
\subparaindent=\skip85
\beforesubparaskip=\skip86
\aftersubparaskip=\skip87
\pfbreakskip=\skip88
\c@@ppsavesec=\count184
\c@@ppsaveapp=\count185
\ragrparindent=\dimen139
\everylistparindent=\dimen140
\parsepi=\skip89
\topsepi=\skip90
\itemsepi=\skip91
\parsepii=\skip92
\topsepii=\skip93
\topsepiii=\skip94
\itemsepii=\skip95
\itemsepiii=\skip96
\partopsepii=\skip97
\partopsepiii=\skip98
\m@msavetopsep=\skip99
\m@msavepartopsep=\skip100
\@enLab=\toks15
\abstitleskip=\skip101
\absleftindent=\skip102
\abs@leftindent=\dimen141
\absrightindent=\skip103
\absparindent=\skip104
\absparsep=\skip105
\c@vslineno=\count186
\c@poemline=\count187
\c@modulo@vs=\count188
\c@memfvsline=\count189
\vleftskip=\skip106
\vrightskip=\skip107
\stanzaskip=\skip108
\versewidth=\skip109
\vgap=\skip110
\vindent=\skip111
\vleftmargin=\dimen142
\c@verse=\count190
\c@chrsinstr=\count191
\beforepoemtitleskip=\skip112
\afterpoemtitleskip=\skip113
\c@poem=\count192
\beforePoemTitleskip=\skip114
\midPoemTitleskip=\skip115
\afterPoemTitleskip=\skip116

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty
Package: array 2020/10/01 v2.5c Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen143
\ar@mcellbox=\box47
\extrarowheight=\dimen144
\NC@list=\toks16
\extratabsurround=\skip117
\backup@length=\skip118
\ar@cellbox=\box48
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/dcolumn.sty
Package: dcolumn 2014/10/28 v1.06 decimal alignment package (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/delarray.sty
Package: delarray 2014/10/28 v1.01 array delimiter package (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty
Package: tabularx 2020/01/15 v2.11c `tabularx' package (DPC)
\TX@col@width=\dimen145
\TX@old@table=\dimen146
\TX@old@col=\dimen147
\TX@target=\dimen148
\TX@delta=\dimen149
\TX@cols=\count193
\TX@ftn=\toks17
)
\heavyrulewidth=\dimen150
\lightrulewidth=\dimen151
\cmidrulewidth=\dimen152
\belowrulesep=\dimen153
\belowbottomsep=\dimen154
\aboverulesep=\dimen155
\abovetopsep=\dimen156
\cmidrulesep=\dimen157
\cmidrulekern=\dimen158
\defaultaddspace=\dimen159
\@cmidla=\count194
\@cmidlb=\count195
\@aboverulesep=\dimen160
\@belowrulesep=\dimen161
\@thisruleclass=\count196
\@lastruleclass=\count197
\@thisrulewidth=\dimen162
\ctableftskip=\skip119
\ctabrightskip=\skip120
\abovecolumnspenalty=\count198
\@linestogo=\count199
\@cellstogo=\count266
\@cellsincolumn=\count267
\crtok=\toks18
\@mincolumnwidth=\dimen163
\c@newflo@tctr=\count268
\mem@margin@floatbox=\box49
\@contcwidth=\skip121
\@contindw=\skip122
\abovecaptionskip=\skip123
\belowcaptionskip=\skip124
\subfloattopskip=\skip125
\subfloatcapskip=\skip126
\subfloatcaptopadj=\skip127
\subfloatbottomskip=\skip128
\subfloatlabelskip=\skip129
\subfloatcapmargin=\dimen164
\c@@contsubnum=\count269
\m@mscap@capbox=\box50
\m@mscap@fbox=\box51
\sidecapsep=\dimen165
\sidecapwidth=\dimen166
\m@m@tempdima=\dimen167
\m@mscapraise=\dimen168
\sidecapraise=\dimen169
\m@mscapmainwidth=\dimen170
\m@mscaplkern=\dimen171
\beforeepigraphskip=\skip130
\afterepigraphskip=\skip131
\epigraphwidth=\skip132
\epigraphrule=\skip133
LaTeX Info: Redefining \em on input line 7678.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \emph on input line 7686.
\tocentryskip=\skip134
\tocbaseline=\skip135
\cftparskip=\skip136
\cftbeforebookskip=\skip137
\cftbookindent=\dimen172
\cftbooknumwidth=\dimen173
\cftbeforepartskip=\skip138
\cftpartindent=\skip139
\cftpartnumwidth=\skip140
\cftbeforechapterskip=\skip141
\cftchapterindent=\skip142
\cftchapternumwidth=\skip143
\cftbeforesectionskip=\skip144
\cftsectionindent=\skip145
\cftsectionnumwidth=\skip146
\cftbeforesubsectionskip=\skip147
\cftsubsectionindent=\skip148
\cftsubsectionnumwidth=\skip149
\cftbeforesubsubsectionskip=\skip150
\cftsubsubsectionindent=\skip151
\cftsubsubsectionnumwidth=\skip152
\cftbeforeparagraphskip=\skip153
\cftparagraphindent=\skip154
\cftparagraphnumwidth=\skip155
\cftbeforesubparagraphskip=\skip156
\cftsubparagraphindent=\skip157
\cftsubparagraphnumwidth=\skip158
\prechapterprecisshift=\dimen174
\c@maxsecnumdepth=\count270
\bibindent=\dimen175
\bibitemsep=\skip159
\indexcolsep=\skip160
\indexrule=\skip161
\indexmarkstyle=\toks19
\@indexbox=\insert252
\glossarycolsep=\dimen176
\glossaryrule=\dimen177
\sideparvshift=\skip162
\sideins=\insert251
\sidebartopsep=\skip163
\sidebarhsep=\skip164
\sidebarvsep=\skip165
\sidebarwidth=\skip166
\footmarkwidth=\skip167
\footmarksep=\skip168
\footparindent=\skip169
\footinsdim=\skip170
\footinsv@r=\insert250
\@mpfootinsv@r=\insert249
\m@m@k=\count271
\m@m@h=\dimen178
\m@mipn@skip=\skip171
\sidefootins=\insert248
\sidefootadjust=\skip172
\sidefootheight=\skip173
\sidefoothsep=\skip174
\sidefootvsep=\skip175
\sidefootwidth=\skip176
\m@mdownsf=\skip177
\c@sidefootnote=\count272
\sidefootmarkwidth=\skip178
\sidefootmarksep=\skip179
\sidefootparindent=\skip180
\c@pagenote=\count273
\c@pagenoteshadow=\count274
\mem@pn@lastkern=\skip181
\every@verbatim=\toks20
\afterevery@verbatim=\toks21
\verbatim@line=\toks22
\tab@position=\count275
\verbatim@in@stream=\read2
\verbatimindent=\skip182
\verbatim@out=\write3
\bvboxsep=\skip183
\c@memfbvline=\count276
\c@bvlinectr=\count277
\bvnumlength=\skip184
\fb@frw=\dimen179
\fb@frh=\dimen180
\FrameRule=\dimen181
\FrameSep=\dimen182
\c@cp@cntr=\count278
\c@ism@mctr=\count279
\c@xsm@mctr=\count280
\c@csm@mctr=\count281
\c@ksm@mctr=\count282
\c@xksm@mctr=\count283
\c@cksm@mctr=\count284
\c@msm@mctr=\count285
\c@xmsm@mctr=\count286
\c@cmsm@mctr=\count287
\c@bsm@mctr=\count288
\c@workm@mctr=\count289
\c@sheetsequence=\count290
\c@lastsheet=\count291
\c@lastpage=\count292

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty
Package: textcase 2019/09/14 v1.00 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
)
\c@figure=\count293
\c@lofdepth=\count294
\cftbeforefigureskip=\skip185
\cftfigureindent=\skip186
\cftfigurenumwidth=\skip187
\c@table=\count295
\c@lotdepth=\count296
\cftbeforetableskip=\skip188
\cfttableindent=\skip189
\cfttablenumwidth=\skip190
Package abstract [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package appendix [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package booktabs [2016/05/16] emulated by memoir.
Package ccaption [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package changepage [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package chngcntr [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package chngpage [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package crop emulated by memoir.
Package enumerate [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package epigraph [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package ifmtarg [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package index [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package makeidx [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package moreverb [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package mparhack [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package needspace [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package newfile [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package nextpage [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package pagenote [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package parskip [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package patchcmd [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package setspace [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package shortvrb [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package showidx [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package titleref [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package titling [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package tocbibind [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package tocloft [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package tocvsec2 [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package verbatim [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package verse [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2021-01-09 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
File: l3backend-xetex.def 2020-01-29 L3 backend support: XeTeX

(|extractbb --version)
\c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int=\count297
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count298
\g__graphics_track_int=\count299
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box52
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count300
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count301
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count302
))
Package: xparse 2020-10-27 L3 Experimental document command parser

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse-generic.tex))
Package: fontspec 2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
Package: fontspec-xetex 2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count303
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count304
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count305
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count306
\l__fontspec_tmpa_int=\count307
\l__fontspec_tmpb_int=\count308
\l__fontspec_tmpc_int=\count309
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count310
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count311
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count312
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count313
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen183
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen184
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen185

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2020/08/10 v2.0s Standard LaTeX package
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))

Package fontspec Info: Font family 'EBGaramond(0)' created for font 'EB
(fontspec)             Garamond' with options [Ligatures=TeX].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"EB
(fontspec)             Garamond/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;"

(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: <->"EB
(fontspec)             Garamond/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+smcp;mapping=tex-
text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (b/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"EB
(fontspec)             Garamond/B/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;mapping=tex-text
;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (b/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"EB
(fontspec)             Garamond/I/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;mapping=tex-text
;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/scit) with NFSS spec.: <->"EB
(fontspec)             Garamond/I/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+smcp;mapping=te
x-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (b/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"EB
(fontspec)             Garamond/BI/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;mapping=tex-tex
t;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (b/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"EB
(fontspec)             Garamond/BI/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+smcp;mapping=t
ex-text;"


(./c6115e0d-b62d-4c15-841a-e1ca4c95cf7f.aux)
\openout1 = `c6115e0d-b62d-4c15-841a-e1ca4c95cf7f.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 5
.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.

Package fontspec Info: Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid
(fontspec)             this).

\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \colon on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> TU/EBGaramond(0)/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/EBGaramond(0)/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  TU/EBGaramond(0)/m/n --> TU/EBGaramond(0)/m/n on input 
line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> TU/EBGaramond(0)/m/it on input line 5.

LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/EBGaramond(0)/b/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> TU/lmss/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/EBGaramond(0)/m/n --> TU/EBGaramond(0)/b/n on input 
line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> TU/EBGaramond(0)/b/it on input line 5
.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> TU/lmss/b/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/b/n on input line 5.
Missing character: There is no ř in font EB Garamond 12 Bold/OT:script=latn;lan
guage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no í in font EB Garamond 12 Bold/OT:script=latn;lan
guage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no š in font EB Garamond 12 Bold/OT:script=latn;lan
guage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ž in font EB Garamond 12 Bold/OT:script=latn;lan
guage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ť in font EB Garamond 12 Bold/OT:script=latn;lan
guage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no č in font EB Garamond 12 Bold/OT:script=latn;lan
guage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ý in font EB Garamond 12 Bold/OT:script=latn;lan
guage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ů in font EB Garamond 12 Bold/OT:script=latn;lan
guage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ň in font EB Garamond 12 Bold/OT:script=latn;lan
guage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ú in font EB Garamond 12 Bold/OT:script=latn;lan
guage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ě in font EB Garamond 12 Bold/OT:script=latn;lan
guage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ď in font EB Garamond 12 Bold/OT:script=latn;lan
guage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no á in font EB Garamond 12 Bold/OT:script=latn;lan
guage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no é in font EB Garamond 12 Bold/OT:script=latn;lan
guage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ó in font EB Garamond 12 Bold/OT:script=latn;lan
guage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ř in font EB Garamond 12 Bold/OT:script=latn;lan
guage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no í in font EB Garamond 12 Bold/OT:script=latn;lan
guage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no š in font EB Garamond 12 Bold/OT:script=latn;lan
guage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ž in font EB Garamond 12 Bold/OT:script=latn;lan
guage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ť in font EB Garamond 12 Bold/OT:script=latn;lan
guage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no č in font EB Garamond 12 Bold/OT:script=latn;lan
guage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ý in font EB Garamond 12 Bold/OT:script=latn;lan
guage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ů in font EB Garamond 12 Bold/OT:script=latn;lan
guage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ň in font EB Garamond 12 Bold/OT:script=latn;lan
guage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ú in font EB Garamond 12 Bold/OT:script=latn;lan
guage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ě in font EB Garamond 12 Bold/OT:script=latn;lan
guage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ď in font EB Garamond 12 Bold/OT:script=latn;lan
guage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no á in font EB Garamond 12 Bold/OT:script=latn;lan
guage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no é in font EB Garamond 12 Bold/OT:script=latn;lan
guage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ó in font EB Garamond 12 Bold/OT:script=latn;lan
guage=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ا in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ل in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ع in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no َ in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ر in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no َ in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ب in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ِ in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ي in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no َ in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ّ in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ة in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no  in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ט in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ו in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ן in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ב in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no י in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ץ in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no  in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no  in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no  in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no  in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ☺ in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ️ in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no  in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ♥ in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ️ in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no  in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ️ in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no  in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no  in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ♂ in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ️ in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no  in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no  in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no  in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no  in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no  in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ♂ in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ️ in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no  in font EB Garamond 12 Regular/OT:script=latn;
language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
 [1


]
(./c6115e0d-b62d-4c15-841a-e1ca4c95cf7f.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 6217 strings out of 477220
 141141 string characters out of 5832722
 499836 words of memory out of 5000000
 25935 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 403582 words of font info for 46 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 81i,10n,89p,333b,233s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on c6115e0d-b62d-4c15-841a-e1ca4c95cf7f.pdf (1 page).
```

### Public docker image

`kolisko/latex:v0.7`

### Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:11
ENV JAVA_OPTS -Xmx256m -Xms256m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=128m

# Latex packages
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y texlive-latex-recommended texlive-fonts-recommended && \
    apt-get install -y texlive-latex-extra texlive-fonts-extra texlive-lang-all texlive-font-utils texlive-xetex && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392144/xelatex-and-fontspec-crash-trying-to-find-woff-file-for-some-fonts-but-not-other
# for fixing error "xdvipdfmx:fatal: Cannot proceed without the font: /usr/share/font/woff/ebgaramond/EBGaramond08-Regular.woff"
RUN echo '<fontconfig>\n\
<!-- Reject WOFF fonts We dont register WOFF(2) fonts with fontconfig because of the W3C spec -->\n\
 <selectfont>\n\
  <rejectfont>\n\
   <glob>*.woff</glob>\n\
  </rejectfont>\n\
 </selectfont>\n\
</fontconfig>' > /etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-woff.conf
```

## Useful commands for simulate the behaviour

#### on host OS - run docker container

```
$ docker run -it kolisko/latex:v0.7 bash
```

#### on host OS - get container id

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                                                                                                                                 NAMES
8f01597b1dc7   kolisko/latex:v0.7    "bash"                   2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes
```

#### on host OS - copy .tex file to container

```
$ docker cp file.tex 8f01597b1dc7:/
```

#### inside container - generate pdf

```
# xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode file.tex
```

#### on host OS - copy .pdf file from container to host OS

```
$ docker cp  8f01597b1dc7:/file.pdf .
```

#### inside container - show installed packages

```
# dpkg -l
```

Comment: Just for fun, have you tried using `lualatex` instead? Xelatex can be very very harsh as to where it looks for fonts. `lualatex` is more forgiving.

Comment: @daleif tried it just now but same result

Comment: @daleif by the way `lualatex` show me the font paths which is cool. It looks that `lualatex` on my MacOS is using different fonts `</Users/kolisko/Library/Fonts/EBGaramond-Italic.ttf></Users/kolisko/Library/Fon
ts/EBGaramond-Regular.ttf></Users/kolisko/Library/Fonts/EBGaramond-Bold.ttf>` than the container which is using `</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/ebgaramond/EBGaramond12-It
alic.otf></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/ebgaramond/EBGara
mond12-Regular.otf></usr/share/fonts/opentype/ebgaramond/EBGaramond12-Bold.otf>`. Maybe it could be the problem?

Comment: No idea, I don't use docker or latex via a linux dist (I use upstream TL21). When I compile it, everything works except the missing char boxes the last four lines like in your picture. Mine is using `opentype/public/ebgaramond/EBGaramond-Italic.otf`, `opentype/public/ebgaramond/EBGaramond-Regular.otf` and `opentype/public/ebgaramond/EBGaramond-Bold.otf`, the supported chars in those two fonts are probably not the same.

Comment: this is almost certainly the version of the fonts or the version of xdvipdfmx in use, docker is very unlikley to be involved really. Push the host fonts to docker and see what happens...

Comment: There exists two versions of the font. Use lualatex, it will report the fonts loaded in the log, then you can better compare the working version and the failing one.